# CSVHelper - Trouble with special Characters

Tags: c#, csvhelper

For our current project, i am using the CSVHelper Nuget and everything works perfectly with it with the only exception when the field contains special characters (ä,ü,...). How can I change it to make it work and not show ? as the letter replacement? (I tried Current and Invariant Culture but it didn't matter).

I tried changing the Culture when reading the byte stream from the file and I tried using different Cultures when parsing the CSV.

Comment: Which encoding are you using, and what does the file actually contain? Please show relevant code, and a sample of the CSV

Comment: Yes, this is a matter of Encoding not Culture

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often have this issue when someone saves an Excel file as `CSV (Comma delimited)(*.csv)` rather than as `CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited)(*.csv)`.  Depending on the country it is saved in, this often means it was saved as Windows 1252 encoding. In most cases, you can get away with using `ISO-8859-1` encoding, also known as `Latin-1` encoding, when reading the file with `StreamReader`. If you still have some characters that are not getting read correctly, you may have to use the exact encoding that was used to save the file.

> ISO-8859-1 (also called Latin-1) is identical to Windows-1252 (also called CP1252) except for the code points 128-159 (0x80-0x9F). ISO-8859-1 assigns several control codes in this range. Windows-1252 has several characters, punctuation, arithmetic and business symbols assigned to these code points. https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/table-iso8859-1-vs-windows-1252.html

In .NET Core it looks like you are a bit limited as to the number of encodings available to you.

> The [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding?view=net-7.0) produces the following output when run on .NET Core:

| Info.CodePage | Info.Name | Info.DisplayName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1200 | utf-16 | Unicode |
| 1201 | utf-16BE | Unicode (Big-Endian) |
| 12000 | utf-32 | Unicode (UTF-32) |
| 12001 | utf-32BE | Unicode (UTF-32 Big-Endian) |
| 20127 | us-ascii | US-ASCII |
| 28591 | iso-8859-1 | Western European (ISO) |
| 65000 | utf-7 | Unicode (UTF-7) |
| 65001 | utf-8 | Unicode (UTF-8) |

```cs
void Main()
{
    using var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\myName\Documents\TestUmlauts.csv", 
        Encoding.Latin1);
    using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    
    var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
}

public class Foo 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```